# Retrieve categories from Spark ML OneHotEncoder?

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-ml

I've used a OneHotEncoder in a Spark ML pipeline:

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import StringIndexer, OneHotEncoder, VectorAssembler

schema = StructType(
  [StructField("PassengerId", DoubleType()),
    StructField("Survived", DoubleType()),
    StructField("Pclass", DoubleType()),
    StructField("Name", StringType()),
    StructField("Sex", StringType()),
    StructField("Age", DoubleType()),
    StructField("SibSp", DoubleType()),
    StructField("Parch", DoubleType()),
    StructField("Ticket", StringType()),
    StructField("Fare", DoubleType()),
    StructField("Cabin", StringType()),
    StructField("Embarked", StringType())
  ])

titanic = (
    spark
    .read
    .option("header", "true")
    .schema(schema)
    .csv("/working_dir/data/titanic.csv")
    .na.fill(0)
    .na.fill("Nulo")
)
trainDF, testDF = titanic.randomSplit([0.8, 0.2], seed=42)

indexers = [StringIndexer(inputCol=c, outputCol=c + "_index", handleInvalid="keep") for c in ["Sex", "Embarked"]]
ohe = OneHotEncoder(inputCols=[indexer.getOutputCol() for indexer in indexers], outputCols=[f"{indexer.getInputCol()}_onehot" for indexer in indexers])
vectorAssembler = (
    VectorAssembler()
    .setInputCols(["Sex_onehot", "Embarked_onehot", "Pclass", "Age", "Fare"])
    .setOutputCol("features")
)
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[
    *indexers,
    ohe,
    vectorAssembler
])
trainDF, testDF = titanic.randomSplit([0.8, 0.2], seed=42)
fitted_pipeline = pipeline.fit(trainDF)
```

Now, I would like to retrieve the categories created for each variable, in a similar fashion as with sklearn:

```
>>> enc.get_feature_names_out(['gender', 'group'])
array(['gender_Female', 'gender_Male', 'group_1', 'group_2', 'group_3'], ...)
```

I've tried printing the ParamMap to see if I could extract them from there, with no luck.
Is there any way to obtain something similar to what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so I figured it out.

```py
def get_input_cols(fitted_pipeline, test_df):    
    schema_attrs = (
        fitted_pipeline
        .transform(contribs)
        .select("features")
        .schema[0]
        .metadata
        .get('ml_attr')
        .get('attrs')
    )

    numeric_attr = schema_attrs.get('numeric') or []
    nominal_attr = schema_attrs.get('nominal') or []
    binary_attr = schema_attrs.get('binary') or []

    numeric = [(item["idx"], item["name"]) for item in numeric_attr]
    binary = [(item["idx"], item["name"]) for item in binary_attr]
    nominal = [(item["idx"], item["name"]) for item in nominal_attr]

    all_attributes = numeric + binary + nominal
    all_attributes = sorted(all_attributes, key=lambda x: x[0])
    
    return all_attributes
```

This returns:

```py
>> get_input_cols(fitted_pipeline, test_df)
[(0, 'Sex_onehot_male'),
 (1, 'Sex_onehot_female'),
 (2, 'Embarked_onehot_S'),
 (3, 'Embarked_onehot_C'),
 (4, 'Embarked_onehot_Q'),
 (5, 'Embarked_onehot_Nulo'),
 (6, 'Pclass'),
 (7, 'Age'),
 (8, 'Fare')]
```